# Reading a hdf5 file, make some processes with Numpy and lmfit accelerated by using multiprocessing

Tags: multidimensional-array, multiprocessing, curve-fitting, hdf5, lmfit

if one of you could help, I would appreciate.
I'm struggling in using multiprocessing to speed up the Gaussian fitting (using lmfit) on a dataset saved as a relatively large hdf5 file (4.3 GB). Please see the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import hdf5plugin

with h5py.File(fname,mode='r', driver='core') as a:
data = np.asarray(a['processed']['result']['data'][()])
q_vector = np.asarray(a['processed']['result']['r_binning'][()])
a.close()

from lmfit import Model
from lmfit import Parameters
from functools import partial

def gauss_function(x, amp, x0, wid):
    return (amp / np.sqrt(2*np.pi*wid))*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*wid**2))

def parameters(x,arr):
    mean = 0
    sigma = 0
    amplitude = 0
    mean = sum(x*arr)/sum(arr)
    sigma = np.sqrt(sum(arr * (x-mean)**2)/sum(arr))
    amplitude = max(arr)
    return (mean,sigma,amplitude)

def fitting_curve(x,arr):
    mean,sigma,amplitude = parameters(x,arr)
    upper_lim = 10**7
    lower_lim = 10**1
    if amplitude == 0 or sigma == 'nan':
        amp_fitted = 0
    else:
        gModel = Model(gauss_function, independent_vars=['x'], param_names=['amp','x0','wid'],nan_policy='omit')
        params = Parameters()
        params = gModel.make_params(amp=amplitude, x0=mean, wid=sigma)
        params.add("amp", value=amplitude)
        params.add("x0", value=mean)
        params.add("wid", value=sigma)
        params['wid'].min = 0.0
        result = gModel.fit(arr, x=x, params=params)
        if lower_lim < result.best_values['amp'] < upper_lim:
            amp_fitted = result.best_values['amp']
        else:
            amp_fitted = 0
    return amp_fitted
```

If I run without multiprocessing it works but it is too slow.

```
def fitting_projections(x,arr_in):
    func_p = partial(fitting_curve,q_vector)
    nr_sec = 4
    arr_out = np.zeros((arr_in.shape[0],arr_in.shape[1],arr_in.shape[2]))
    for k in range(arr_in.shape[0]):
        for m in range(arr_in.shape[1]):
            for o in range (arr_in.shape[2]):
                mean,sigma,amplitude = parameters(x,arr_in[k,m,o,nr_sec,:])
                if amplitude == 0 or sigma == 'nan':
                    arr_out[k,m,o]=0
                else:
                    arr_out[k,m,o]=func_p(arr_in[k,m,o,nr_sec,:])
    return arr_out

arr_output = np.asarray(fitting_projections(q_rec, rec_dataset_corr))
```

However, when I try to speed up the fitting by using the multiprocessing package (code below) I get the error that the hdf5 file cannot be opened.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

n_cores = mp.cpu_count()
print(n_cores)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func_p = partial(fitting_curve,q_vector)
    arr_out = np.zeros((data.shape[0],data.shape[1],data.shape[3]))
    pool=mp.Pool(n_cores-1)
    for k in range(data.shape[0]):
        for m in range(data.shape[1]):
            try:
                arr_out[k,m,:]= pool.map(func_p,(data[k,m,:,o] for o in range(0,data.shape[3])))
            except:
                pass
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
    OSError: [Errno 22] Unable to open file (file read failed: time = Tue Jan 17 15:09:25 2023
, filename = 'K:/11014463/processed/phantom_offline/waxs/merged_data.nxs', file descriptor = 4, errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', file->mem = 00000251DC616040, total read size = 4365954870, bytes this sub-read = 2147483647, bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 0)
```

I'm running on `Python 3.9.15`

I expect to have in the end a 3D array with the results of the fitting process accelerated by using parallel computing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "open and read data from file" or definition of `data` in your example code, so it is a little hard to know for sure what you are doing.

If you're reading NeXus / HDF5 data, you may need to check that you are passing a real numpy array (and not an HDF5 group) to your worker function.  So, perhaps using

```
  pool.map(func_p,(data[k,m,:,o][()] for o in range(data.shape[3])))
```

would help.

I would suggest including more than just the best-fit value of the amplitude in the returned result, as having uncertainties and fit statistics can help diagnose poor fits or oddities.

Finally, it might be that if your data is reliably Gaussian (ie, no backgrounds or other peaks) that a first pass might be to *just* get the estimated values from your `parameters()` function.  If you have not already done that, I would recommend doing so, and then refining those values with a real fit.